# How to draw continues lines across panels in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, datepart

I want to plot a couple of measures by months over the last three years. The plot would be divided by year. So I put `year` and `month` for columns and the measure values for rows. The `year` is defined as `DATEPART('year', [Month Date])` and `month` is `DATEPART('month', [Month Date])`.

The plot looks like this.
[image]

The lines are broken between years. Both `YEAR` and `MONTH` are blue (discrete), but if I change them to green (continuous), the lines are connected but it looks weird. 
[image]

I wonder how to make continuous lines across year?

Comment: did my below response help?

Comment: @ddd I am have the same issue and smb response did not help. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is you have converted a date part (i.e. Month = March) to a continuous unit. What this does is simply changes March to 3. This looses the context of what the actual date is (i.e. March 2007). To change this right click on the date field on the column. You will see two separate areas to format the dates i.e. there are two years (2015, 2015), two quarters (Q2 and Q2 2015) etc. The first is a date part and the second is truncated date from the original date/timestamp.

You want to change the format to the second Month option (Month May 2015) and ensure the data type is continuous. 
This should give you a continuous line across the year. If not screenshot me where you get to and I can assist from there.

Comment: Good answer, but the more precise description is that the first section of date transformations in the menu extract *date parts* from the dates in the original data, and that the second section of date transformations create *truncated dates* from the original dates. Either can be set to discrete or continuous to impact presentation. Read about the functions date_part() and date_trunc() for details. Finally, a date in Tableau is a compound date type with three mandatory components (month, day and year). Date parts are not dates, but truncated dates are dates.

Comment: Is May 2015 for continuous data a default value? Can you tell me more about the date i mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the last week and first of the next year is the same, I have a similar issue and solved it by passing the dates as Day-Month-Year.

Comment: you mean instead of `year` and `month`, use `day-month-year` instead for column. How exactly is `day-month-year` calculated?

Comment: You don't have days in you database or table?, making it more specific to Tableu in where to look, can solve pretty easy this issue, otherwise try with the other answer, I think it could work too. Best of luck